# How to get OpenTable link from a Google Place detail

Tags: google-places-api, cross-reference

I have a google places detail json, obtained from Google Place search API. (in iOS)
I need to obtain the link to OpenTable if exists.

**Here an example**
Bent Fork American Grill in Aurora

**Some data from Google Place**:

reference = "CoQBeQAAABr_ao_RIx8ZBRPp-_AHIvZWvxCiB37z9fzIbHpHIEiBjuRR3ozwYENHFQMOPzULNAZI9jzBAuvJ0_C3rxSFNQEtARJCZsFCjtG2ahq0gMetMz3B9KlZ6zW8lj0-o3VTou1OCiYe7RSOeCqPTfVr-G0KuDivrhIkOyGERstq5eZYEhAeyXIUIVEcI1yR4qmq1w2lGhRHZ0f0Kb6NRbrN4YTIGP1mHxEzAg";

id = 752488936cbfabccf3b0edc92f86fc960a43b052;

url = "https://plus.google.com/102338530653181014648/about?hl=en";

If I go to the url of this place, there is a link to OpenTable of the same restaurant.
http://www.opentable.com/rest_profile_reviews.aspx?rid=15292&ref=1068

I need a way to obtain that link without going into the url.
From iOS I cannot download the html to look for the link.  Well, I shouldn't

Thanks in advance,
Marce.